# Chroot from Debian livecd

Tags: bash, livecd, chroot

I'm trying to repair LILO on a Debian server. I'm trying to chroot, with

chroot /mnt/boot /etc/csh

and I get:

chroot: cannot run command '/etc/csh': Permission denied

How can I perform a chroot?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want /bin/csh instead of /etc/csh

Comment: There is no /bin on the mounted partition, only file directories and a /etc. Probably all other Linux data is on two other disks which operated in raid1 (it's not my server by the way, and the guy who installed it has graduated and moved). There is a /etc/csh in the mounted partition.

Comment: On my system, `etc/csh` is a directory.

Comment: On my system, /etc/csh is a shell. I've checked and I can run it. However I cannot use it to chroot.

Comment: @Auke: Binary executables aren't supposed to live in `/etc`.